# How to test differences in budget allocations

Tags: chi-squared-test, nonparametric, ordinal-data, marginal-distribution, compositional-data

Suppose a grant program allows city administrators to allocate the grant across three mutually exclusive categories `1, 2, 3`.

City administrators are surveyed to elicit their preferred allocations.  A response by administrator `i` is a triplet `R_i = (p1, p2, p3)`, where by definition: `0 <= pi <= 100` for all `i` in `{1,2,3}` and `p3 = 100 - p1 - p2`.  In words, `p1, p2, p3` represent the proportion of grant money he or she would allocate to each of three categories `1, 2, 3`.

Suppose 80 administrators are surveyed.  Of these 34 selected at random had previously received a prompt meant to shift the distribution of allocations in favor of `p1`, at the expense of the other two items.  The motivation is that the grantor of money has preference ordering `1 > 2 > 3`.

I want to test the null that elicited budget allocations across treatment and control are the same, against the one-sided alternative of a location shift towards `p1`. Due to small sample size, I am mostly interested in non-parametric approaches.

An obvious possibility is to test `p1_T = p1_C`, for treatment and control, against `p1_T > p1_C`.  But I am not sure this makes the most effective use of the information, as any such difference must also  imply a decline in `p2_T` or `p3_T` or both relative to control. In addition, I am not sure marginal test of homogeneity (like Chi square test) offer a directed alternative.

For these reasons I am considering a weighted response like `Y = p1*1 + p2*2 + p3*3` for each administrator, as the categories are ordered. The alternative would then be `Y_T  < Y_C`.

Is this correct? Any suggestions and rationale?

Comment: Would an analysis geared toward *mixture designs* fit here?

Comment: @rolando2 I don't think so.  In mixture designs the treatment is a mixture.  By contrast, here it is the outcome that is a mixture.  We want to test the effect of treatment on the mixture proportions.